# TimeSpan to ISO8601 duration format string

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone advise on how to convert a timespan or int to an ISO8601 duration string as explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations?

"1 hour and 30 minutes" would result in "PT1H30M", for example:

```
int duration = 90;
string isoString = duration.ToIsoDuration();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an ISO8601 TimeSpan to a C# TimeSpan?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466188/how-do-i-convert-an-iso8601-timespan-to-a-c-sharp-timespan)

Comment: NOT a duplicate - parsing and representing as a string are separate operations.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

found the solution myself, so I thought I'd share:

```
   TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, value, 0);
   return XmlConvert.ToString(timeSpan);
```

Comment: In the first line, you can also say `TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(value);` That's more clear in my opinion.

Comment: That's nice for short durations, but it stops working as soon as you have months- or years-long durations, because TimeSpan cannot represent those durations. It just converts everything back to days, which is incorrect since not all months have the same number of days.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just thought I'd mention the PowerShell equivalent is `[System.Xml.XmlConvert]::ToString($timespan)`.

Answer (score 0):

As the dupe question mentions LUIS, it can also produce more complex timex expressions.

One can generate or parse them using the same lib as LUIS uses: https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).