# How can I parse this timespan string?

Tags: c#, timespan, iso, duration, formats

I have timespan : "P3M10DT5H2M"
I m trying to parse  with these codes:

```
var timespan =  "P3M10DT5H2M"
string[] formats = new[] { "'PT's'S'", "'PT'm'M'", "'P'd'D'", "'PT'h'H'", "'P'd'DT'h'H'", "'P'd'DT'h'H'm'M'", "'PT'h'H'm'M'", "'P'd'DT'h'H'm'M's'S'", "'P'm'M'd'DT'h'H'm'M'" };
TimeSpan.ParseExact((string)timespan , formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But this  error occurs:
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.

The last format should be match for this string but not why? And also the other question my way is not so good. Because I have to write all possibilities in formats. So Should I use regular expressions instead of formats array. Please help me.

Comment: variable `timespan` and `tmespan` are not the same.

Comment: I edited now, sorry. But it s not because of that.

Comment: Please parse "P3M10DT5H2M" **manually** so that we know what its parts are. Specifically you have two "M"s what do they mean?

Comment: First one is for month, other one for minute. The time is  actually 3 months,10 Days,5 Hours, 2 Minutes

Comment: How did you setup these `formats`? Are these standard formats ?

Comment: Yes these are  .NET TimeSpans to ISO 8601 Duration strings.

Comment: Did you consider using `System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan()`?

Comment: Look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466188/how-do-i-convert-an-iso8601-timespan-to-a-c-sharp-timespan

Comment: Yes I used System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan. I dont have to use formats. Really thanks...