# Parse YouTube ISO 8601 to DateTime C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, youtube-api, iso8601

In The YouTube v3 Developer API, when retrieving [the video duration](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties) it's returned in ISO 8601 format.

How can I parse this as a DateTime object in C#?

Here's an example: PT5M58S

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3556144/1715004

Comment: I have read that but the format of the string in that thread is different and wouldn't work for this. I've tried the flagged answer and it was throwing an unrecognised format exception

Comment: Actually, you should use TimeSpan as it is a time interval.

Comment: this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12466271/1715004

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TimeSpan ts = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("PT5M58S");
```

Best option is to convert to a TimeSpan instead of a DateTime.

From the MS docs on TimeSpan (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timespan):

> Represents a time interval.