# c# datatype for json time

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I got the following json result from a rest api and I am using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize it to a c# object.

```
    {
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "Aufnr": "4000103",
        "Workdate": "/Date(1482796800000)/",
        "Beguz": "PT07H30M00S",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`Aufnr` and `Workdate` are working with `String` and `DateTime`, but I got no clue which datatype to use for `Beguz`

I tried `TimeSpan` and `DateTime` and got this error: `Error converting value "PT07H30M00S" to type 'System.TimeSpan'. Path '[0].Beguz'`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would be String wrong?

Comment: That is a string,isn't it? I guess that it contains a time (07:30:00) but with that format is a string. You could add a property to your object to "translate" it to datetime, or use a custom converter

Comment: to me this look like a timespan format. You need to parse it manually do

Comment: @J.Steen _"Nowhere near a standardized format"_ - [is ISO 8601 standardized enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466188/how-do-i-convert-an-iso8601-timespan-to-a-c-sharp-timespan)? ;)

Comment: @CodeCaster Holy crap, I was looking through the ISO8601 before I posted that comment - very briefly I admit - but missed that! My extreme bad.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/863).You've got a example custom converter that may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pure string:

```
public string Beguz { get; set; }
```

Of course if you want this `PT07H30M00S` string to be represented by some complex custom structure you could write a [`custom JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to achieve this task. In this converter you will need to provide the logic of how to parse this string back to some custom structure of yours.