# keep date format the same when representing a date or a timespan

Tags: c#, date, datetime, iso8601

In our api we need to receive parameters for dates and also for time-spans, but we need to be consistent with the format.

What is the ISO standard to represent in the same form a date and also a time-span?

I've seen [ISO 8601 Date and Time Formats](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats) but I don't see how to represent a date using this format...

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by a time-span here? ISO-8601 dates are just yyyy-MM-dd (or yyyyMMdd) but they definitely don't represent timespans. The idea of trying to use the same format for both dates and timespans makes no sense to me... *why* are you trying to use the same format?

Comment: @JonSkeet We need to represent like from date X to date Y and also to put just a date, but we want to keep the same format if it is possible

Comment: And with this standard we can represent a timespan like "P2M5D" (2 months and 5 days)

Comment: Apparently [XmlConvert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466188/how-do-i-convert-an-iso8601-timespan-to-a-c-sharp-timespan) can handle it.

Comment: I know that, but I've asked about the date format, not how to convert a string to a date or timespan

Comment: But "date X to date Y" and "date X" are *not the same thing* - why would you want to represent them in the same way? And yes, ISO-8601 does have things like P2M5D, but again that's different from a date or even a date range. It's very, very unclear what your API is trying to represent and what you're really asking about.

Comment: Buda How would you represent a datetime in the same way as a timespan? How would you represent 5 months? The representations are not the same because the data is not the same.