# Haven't seen this time format before "PT5M37S"

Tags: c#

I am accessing an API that returns a time field like this: `"PT5M37S"`.

How do I get this time string `"PT5M37S"` into `00:05:37`? Anyone have any insight on that time format?

Comment: It's an ISO8601 duration, if that helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Comment: This API, is it perchance a wrapper around the Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an ISO8601 TimeSpan to a C# TimeSpan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466188/how-do-i-convert-an-iso8601-timespan-to-a-c-sharp-timespan)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.totimespan?view=net-5.0