# Reading PT0S to 0 second using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file giving me the value  PT0S.

```
 <Property name="TargetQuantity" type="double">
        <Value>PT0S</Value>
 </Property>
```

I have to store this value in a DATABASE table field - which is of type decimal. I have no idea how to convert this value to decimal. I am using C# to process this value.
I tried to use

```
Convert.ToDecimal
```

But it does not work.
Any advices would be helpful.

Comment: What decimal value do you want to turn "PT0S" into? Without that information, there's no possible way we can help you

Comment: To answer your question - PT0S should be read as 0 seconds. What I understand this is a specific format. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations. This tends me to think we have to process this string. I was wondering if there is a better way to read this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly convert a timespan to a decimal. You need to decide which property you want.

See [How do I convert an ISO8601 TimeSpan to a C# TimeSpan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466188/how-do-i-convert-an-iso8601-timespan-to-a-c-sharp-timespan) ([`XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.totimespan?view=net-6.0)), and then for example save [`TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalseconds?view=net-6.0) in your decimal column.