# How do I convert an integer into an ISO8601 TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

This is my input:

```
55
```

This is my desired output:

```
PT55H
```

Is there a built in class in C# that converts a timespan as: `TimeSpan.TryParse(55)` or as a string "55" with hours into an ISO8601 formatted string?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906022/c-sharp-timespan-to-iso8601-format-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coworker just found this for me:

```
TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(txtStartHours.Text), 0, 0); 
durationNode.Element("StartTime").Value = XmlConvert.ToString(start);
```

It seems to convert it to `PT2D7H`, but since I'm using `XMLConvert.ToTimeSpan().TotalHours` elsewhere, it shouldn't cause any problems!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a number to a `TimeSpan` with the static `TimeSpan.FromHours` method. For example `var ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(55.0);`.

If you always want the time represented with hours only, in the ISO system, maybe you can simply say `var isostring = String.Format("PT{0}H", ts.TotalHours);`.

Comment: this would work but I want something generic for any timespan

Comment: But doesn't it work for any time span? I thought you wanted an hour-only format. Like `PT55H` (55 hours) instead of `P2DT7H` (2 days and 7 hours).

Comment: Ideally, I would like to have hours-only, but with my requirement for being generic, it seems like I have no choice but to do the string handling myself, or allow it to use P2DT7H formatting.'

Comment: For any `TimeSpan ts` (which shouldn't be negative), my `String.Format("PT{0}H", ts.TotalHours)` gives a PT followed by a number of hours (possibly with decimals), followed by an H. You could specify the number of decimals, or the decimal separator character if you wanted.