# DateTime to duration conversion

Tags: c#, xsd

Does c# have support for converting two `DateTime`'s to the `xs:duration` data type? (I'm assuming I need two `DateTime` values for this?)

References: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#duration and http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp (half way down)

Comment: and how do you expect duration to be like? (example: Timespan or a string which says date1-date2 kind of thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# Timespan to ISO8601 format string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906022/c-sharp-timespan-to-iso8601-format-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was support for this in the `XMLConvert` class as explained here: http://kennethxu.blogspot.de/2008/09/xmlserializer-doesn-serialize-timespan.html

I ended up using this code and it displays the value in the xml correct

```
    [XmlElementAttribute("ValidThrough", DataType = "duration")]
    [DataMember(Name = "ValidThrough")]
    [DefaultValue("P10D")]
    public string ValidThrough
    {
        get
        {
            return XmlConvert.ToString(_validThroughField);
        }
        set
        {
            _validThroughField= XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(value);
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public TimeSpan _validThroughField { get; set; }
```

Comment: +1 I will delete my answer as I wasn't aware there was something built in for this.

Answer (score 3):

[TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) is what you are looking for.

> A TimeSpan object **represents a time interval** (duration of time or
>   elapsed time) that is measured as a positive or negative number of
>   days, hours, minutes, seconds, and fractions of a second. The TimeSpan
>   structure can also be used to represent the time of day, but only if
>   the time is unrelated to a particular date. Otherwise, the DateTime or
>   DateTimeOffset structure should be used instead.

Example:

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2012, 10, 2, 10, 20, 00);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan ts = dt1 - dt2;
```

Comment: Is there a helper function to convert this timespan to the format ``P1Y2M3DT10H30M` or is this done automatically when you do `.ToString()`?

Comment: -1 I'm afraid the answer to this question is a little more complex than *"use `TimeSpan`"*. Yes, you will probably need to use the TimeSpan object, however, you will also need to calculate other values which you couldn't reliably work out with `TimeSpan` e.g. No. of months. Also, your implying that `TimeSpan` *does* this conversion for you - which it doesn't.

Comment: `TimeSpan` does not represent long periods accurately. OK for a few days or less. If you need something with precision, look somewhere other than Microsoft.