# How can i convert Minutes into timex

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert Minutes into Timex. So it is exactly like Luis shows its DateTimeRange.
Like so:

450 minutes would be PT7H30M

or

30 minutes would be PT30M

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906022/timespan-to-iso8601-duration-format-string)

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(450);
return XmlConvert.ToString(timeSpan);
```