# How can I parse ISO 8601's "PnDTnHnMn.nS" format in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, date, duration, iso, period

I have a date value in windows console application like this one `"P0Y0M0DT23H43M52.103S"`, and I want to parse this datetime value in c# to get minutes out of datetime value. It is easily done in Java by using `new java.time.Duration.parse("P0Y0M0DT23H43M52.103S").toMinutes()`.

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) for `Duration.parse(CharSequence text)` says:

> This will parse a textual representation of a duration, including the string produced by `toString()`. The formats accepted are based on the ISO-8601 duration format `PnDTnHnMn.nS` with days considered to be exactly 24 hours.

I am looking for a similar functionality in .net c# which can help me workout time in minutes accurately without having to run loop and split.

Thank you

Comment: @Dai It actually is ISO 8601 but not a DateTime value.  It is referred to as a *Duration*.

Comment: @RickDavin Right, I deleted my comment after I did some research.

Comment: .NET itself has no Duration or Period type. You can use a library like NodaTime to work with durations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `TimeSpan` is a duration type.

Comment: I don't know if .NET has such functionality to handle ISO Duration's, but you may try using NodaTime (from NodaTime.org).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906022/timespan-to-iso8601-duration-format-string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466188/how-do-i-convert-an-iso8601-timespan-to-a-c-sharp-timespan

Comment: Try something like: TimeSpan ts = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("P0Y0M0DT23H43M52.103S");

Comment: @Dai it's not the same. A Timespan can't represent months. Adding 1 month to January 30 isn't the same as adding 30 days.

Comment: There's a reason why `Timespan` only supports days, anything bigger is not constant length!

Comment: @PoulBak: Yes, and that makes it a mismatch for an ISO-8601 period, which is Noda Time models both "fixed length durations" and "calendrical periods" but with different types.

Answer (score 3):

You can use my [Noda Time library](https://nodatime.org) and its `Period` type:

```cs
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

var parseResult = PeriodPattern.NormalizingIso.Parse("P0Y0M0DT23H43M52.103S");
if (parseResult.Success)
{
    Period period = parseResult.Value;
    Console.WriteLine($"Success! Parsed to {period}");
}
```

Note that even in Java, parsing an ISO-8601 period as a `Duration` is somewhat inappropriate... durations should be *fixed lengths of time* whereas if you have an ISO-8601 period of something like "P1M", that *isn't* a fixed length of time (ditto years). That's why the `Duration.parse` method requires it to only have days, hours, minutes etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.totimespan):

```
TimeSpan duration = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("P0Y0M0DT23H43M52.103S");
```

Comment: A Timespan of 30 days isn't the same as a period of 1 month

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `java.time.Duration` doesn't quantify months either (for the same obvious reason), so I guess it's exactly what OP wants :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `System.Xml.Schema.XsdDuration` supports only years and days, it doesn't support months.

Comment: @Dai: If there's a number of years, that's just as bad. How many days are in a year? Depends on the year...

Comment: XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan("P0Y0M0DT23H43M52.103S") worked well in .net 6.

Comment: @user3778549 The years, months, and days values are all zero though (`0Y0M0D`).

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression parses ISO-8601 duration strings e.g., P1DT2H, into named groups for easy extraction.

```
(?n)^P(?=.)(((?<CY>\d+)Y)?((?<CM>\d+)M)?((?<CW>\d+)W)?((?<CD>\d+)D)?)?(T(?=.+)(((?<TH>\d+)H)?((?<TM>\d+)M)?((?<TS>\d+)S)?)?)?$
```

See the PowerShell script below for how this was generated.

## PowerShell

This PowerShell script uses regex to parse the ISO8601 duration and then applies the calendar-based time deltas to the specified date.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Adds an ISO-8601 calendar-based duration to a date.
.PARAM Duration
    The duration to add
.PARAM Date
    The reference date, defaults to Now.
.EXAMPLES 
    P1Y: 1 year 
    P1Y2M3W4D: 1 year, 2months, 3 weeks, 4 days 
    PT5H6M7S:  5 hours, 6 minutes, 7 seconds
    P1Y2M3W4DT5H6M7S: 1 year, 2months, 3 weeks, 4 days, 5 hours, 6 minutes, 7 seconds
#>
function Add-Duration {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Duration,
        [DateTime]$Date = (Get-Date),
        [Switch]$Past
    )
    # Compute ISO-8601 duration from the anchor
    $ReCalendarParts=("YMWD".ToCharArray()  | %{ "((?<C$_>\d+)$_)?" }) -join ""
    $ReTimeParts=("HMS".ToCharArray()  | %{ "((?<T$_>\d+)$_)?" }) -join ""
    $ReISO8601P = "(?n)^P(?=.)($ReCalendarParts)?(T(?=.+)($ReTimeParts)?)?$"
    $m = ([Regex]$ReISO8601P).Match($Duration)
    if (-Not $m.Success) { throw "Unexpected -Duration value $Duration. Expected P30D or similar ISO-8601 duration" }
    foreach ($group in $m.Groups) {
        if ($group.Name -ne "0" -and $group.Success) {
            $interval = [int]$group.Value
            if ($Past) { $interval *= -1 }
            $Date = switch -exact ($group.Name) {
                CY { $Date.AddYears($interval) }
                CM { $Date.AddMonths($interval) }
                CW { $Date.AddDays($interval * 7) }
                CD { $Date.AddDays($interval) }
                TH { $Date.AddHours($interval) }
                TM { $Date.AddMinutes($interval) }
                TS { $Date.AddSeconds($interval) }
                default { throw "Unsupported interval $($Group.Name)" }
            }
        }
    }
    $Date
}
```

## C#

This C# code uses regex to parse the ISO8601 duration and then applies the calendar-based time deltas to the specified date.

See the PowerShell example above for how the Regex pattern is constructed.

```
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.AddDuration("PT1H"));

    internal static class DateTimeExtensions
    {

        const string Iso8601DurationPattern = @"(?n)^P(?=.)(((?<CY>\d+)Y)?((?<CM>\d+)M)?((?<CW>\d+)W)?((?<CD>\d+)D)?)?(T(?=.+)(((?<TH>\d+)H)?((?<TM>\d+)M)?((?<TS>\d+)S)?)?)?$";

        private static readonly Regex Iso8601DurationRegex = new Regex(Iso8601DurationPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

        public static DateTime AddDuration(this DateTime value, string duration, bool past = false)
        {
            var match = Iso8601DurationRegex.Match(duration);
            if (!match.Success)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(duration));
            }
            foreach (Group group in match.Groups)
            {
                if (group.Success && group.Name != "0")
                {
                    var interval = Int32.Parse(group.Value);
                    if (past) { interval *= -1; }
                    value = group.Name switch
                    {
                        "CY" => value.AddYears(interval),
                        "CM" => value.AddMonths(interval),
                        "CW" => value.AddDays(interval * 7),
                        "CD" => value.AddDays(interval),
                        "TH" => value.AddHours(interval),
                        "TM" => value.AddMinutes(interval),
                        "TS" => value.AddSeconds(interval),
                        _ => throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported duration element $($Group.Name)")
                    };
                }
            }
            return value;
        }

    }
```