# How to deserialize java duration in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json, nodatime

Assuming that I got a duration from Java: "PT-328H-46M-43.2082074S".
How to deserialize it to NodaTime Duration in system.text.json?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse ISO 8601's "PnDTnHnMn.nS" format in C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74155954/how-can-i-parse-iso-8601s-pndtnhnmn-ns-format-in-c-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the format that Noda Time usually uses for *periods* rather than durations. Unfortunately the presence of multiple signs within the value means you can't parse it using `DurationPattern` - but `PeriodPattern.NormalizingIso` appears to work okay:

```cs
using NodaTime.Text;

var pattern = PeriodPattern.NormalizingIso;
var result = pattern.Parse("PT-328H-46M-43.2082074S");
var period = result.Value;
var duration = period.ToDuration();

Console.WriteLine(duration);
```

To use that within `System.Text.Json`, you'd need to specify the right period pattern... and then potentially sort of "trampoline" from the period to the duration. Here's a complete example:

Program.cs:

```cs
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Serialization.SystemTextJson;
using NodaTime.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

string json = """
{
  "name": "Jon",
  "duration": "PT-328H-46M-43.2082074S"
}
""";

var settings = new NodaJsonSettings
{
    PeriodConverter = new NodaPatternConverter<Period>(PeriodPattern.NormalizingIso)
};
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions().ConfigureForNodaTime(settings);

var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(json, options);
Console.WriteLine(model.Duration);
```

Model.cs:

```cs
using NodaTime;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class Model
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Obsolete]
    [JsonPropertyName("duration")]
    public Period Period
    {
        // TODO: A getter, if you want to be able to serialize back.
        // That's a little more work as there isn't a Duration.ToPeriod conversion.
        set => Duration = value.ToDuration();
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Duration Duration { get; set; }
}
```